# Issue with TYPO3 extension and template

Tags: php, typo3

I am reading a TYPO3 extension.
This is the template file:

```
<!-- ###LIST_LATEST### begin -->
<div class="latest-wrapper">
    <ul class="listing latest">
        <li><h1>###LIST_HEADER###</h1></li>
        <!-- ###LOOP### --><!-- ###ITEM### --><li>
            <span class="category">###CATEGORY###</span><span class="company">###COMPANY_NAME###</span><span class="location">###LOCATION###, ###STATE### ###ZIP###</span>
        </li><!-- ###ITEM### --><!-- ###LOOP### -->
        <li class="more">###MORE###</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- ###LIST_LATEST### end -->
```

In `class.tx_jcjob_pi1.php`, when put the contents into the template file, seems there are two ways:

a. for `###MORE###`, use this method:

```
$markerArray['###MORE###'] = $this->cObj->getTypoLink($this->pi_getLL('text_link_more'), $this->conf['searchID'], array('tx_ajaxsearch_pi1[keyword]' => ''));
$content = $this->cObj->substituteMarkerArray($template, $markerArray);
```

b. for `<!-- ###LOOP### -->`, use this method:

```
$template = $this->cObj->substituteSubpart($template, '###LOOP###', $loopContent);  var_dump($template);
```

So my question is:

1. What is the difference between `###MORE###` and  `<!-- ###LOOP### -->`?
2. What is the difference between `substituteMarkerArray` and `substituteSubpart`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for the difference between two basic templating tools in TYPO3:

1. Markers (`###MORE###`) and
2. Subparts (`<!-- ###LOOP### -->`)

Both are placeholders to be replaced with dynamic content.

A **marker** represents a *singular occurance*. The string `###MORE###` will be replaced by the function `substituteMarker()` or `substituteMarkerArray()` with whatever value you define in your php code.

A **subpart** always occurs in pairs; it has a beginning and an end marker. They enclose a *range of code* within which more values can be replaced. In your case, everything between the two `<!-- ###LOOP### -->` strings you find in your template can be processed by the function `substituteSubpart()`. Usually, this is used for list views when you loop over multiple results from your query. Within each subpart element you can replace markers or subparts recursively in your php code.

[This blog post](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/07/using-templates-in-typo3-frontend.html) might give you some more insight into the principles.